# Ensure different elements choose same class from random list

Tags: javascript

I have some code telling two different classes to choose a new color from a random list on page load.

This is working.

But I'd like to force/ensure that both of the elements choose the same class from the random list.  Now the two elements may choose a different class on load.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
const classes = ["lemon", "blue"];

$("p, a.Header-nav-item").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What’s wrong with storing `classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]` in a separate variable outside the `each` callback?

Answer (score 0):

I was given this answer which works.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
const classes = ["lemon", "blue"];
const randomClass = classes[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length)]

$("p, a.Header-nav-item").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass(randomClass);
});
});
</script>
```